# Regex - Match the pattern of a string representing a variable and its assigned value

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regex pattern that would enable me to swiftly search through my source code to find the following string pattern:

```
placeholder="any text here"
```

I have tried the following regex pattern however, it does not exclusively capture strings beginning with the sub-string "placeholder".

```
placeholder=\".+\"
```

Comment: Works for me: `printf 'foobar\nplaceholder="baz"\n' | egrep 'placeholder=\".+\"'`. Perhaps we could help you figure this out if you provided more detail. Is this occurring in any particular language? What's the actual data you're parsing? How might we replicate your results?

Comment: Are you planning to match C strings? It is a long-solved issue. `placeholder="[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\]*)*"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make lazy, with `?`. Otherwise it captures the maximal possible match. Also, no need to escape the quotes.

```
placeholder=".+?"
```

Comment: Thank you +nicael! It worked perfectly! Is this the best way to capture this pattern? If not, what other means would you recommend?

Comment: @Agot good enough I believe. If I knew the better, I would post it.